# Round df values but exclude given row if named "x"

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

Is there an easy way to round df values but exclude a given row based on name?

This is how I am rounding the values in my df:

```
#multiply value by 100 then round
df = df.applymap(lambda x: int(round(x*100)))
```

However, I want to exclude "Mean" from the rounding. The position/index of "Mean" is unknown, it is not fixed. Number of rows in the df are also unknown.

Below, I have shown how the df looks like "before", how it looks like "after" I apply my code and what I would like the df to look like "desired".

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of the columns?

Comment: Why have a row for the mean like that?

Comment: @cs95 - all floats

Comment: @AMC - market research data looks like this, they do crazy things.

Comment: How many rows are there where you want to round the values versus where you don’t?

Comment: @AMC number of rows are unknown, I'm going to running this code on hundreds of dfs.

Comment: @Boosted_d16 Then how will you know which rows to exclude?

Comment: @AMC - I'm guessing I would search for "Mean" in df.index, if found then I need to exclude it from the rounding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
df.loc[df.index != 'Mean'] = df.applymap(lambda x: int(round(x*100)))
```

Would return

```
       male     female
honda   48.0    24.0
ford    78.0    48.0
nissan  69.0    12.0
jag     47.0    36.0
Mean    102.0   204.0
```

Comment: Absolute legend! Thanks.